# Feed Placeholder with another Placeholder using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following situation:
There is a production server (C++) running tensorflow. The code there expects to have exactly one input `Placeholder`, that gets fed similar to `feed_dict:{'input':...}`. I can't change the server code. I can only provide a new graph, that must have a `Placeholder` called `input`.

Using tensorflow, I have some code that creates two identical neural networks with different scope:

```
dnn1 = DNN(scope='dnn1')
dnn2 = DNN(scope='dnn2')
```

Both DNNs have an input `Placeholder`: 
`<tf.Tensor 'dnn1/input:0' shape=(50) dtype=float32>`
and
`<tf.Tensor 'dnn2/input:0' shape=(50) dtype=float32>`

Both networks should get the same input.
How can I make the tensor `input` flow to both, `dnn1/input` and `dnn2/input` within the graph? I also can't change the `DNN` class, so in the end my graph will have `dnn1/input`,`dnn2/input` and `input` as placeholder, but only `input` will be supplied by the production code.

Comment: why not simply feed your input_data to both input tensors?

Comment: The feeding is done in a production environment, so I need to stick with the current feed of `feed_dict={'input':np.array(...)}` There are many workarounds possible, but I don't want to change other parts of the code.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You need to have some way to feed your data into both networks respectively, right?

Comment: Yes, the main production module (c++) calls something like `feed_dict={'input':np.ones([50])}`, I can't change that. So I need to redirect `input` to both, `dnn1/input` and `dnn2/input`

Comment: And in your python program you only have access to the input-placeholder?

Comment: Yes, in the other program the input placeholder is fixed and can only access `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a input-placeholder and use this as the input to both networks:

Eg DNN1:
`hidden1 = (input * W1) + b1`

DNN2:
`hidden1 = (input * W1) + b1`

Can you do this?

Comment: I want to have the solution within the graph. This would transfer it to memory and re-feed it. That will not work in my case (see update)

Comment: Can you explain the flow of your whole program in detail? Explain Everything that you can change / can't change...

Comment: No, as I cannot change the DNN function. DNN will create the whole MLP, including input placeholders

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the DNN placeholders to take the production input placeholder by default. Thus, you can still feed them custom values anytime you want.

```
session = tf.Session()
production_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [50])

# Own placeholders
dnn_1_input = tf.placeholder_with_default(production_input, [50])
dnn_2_input = tf.placeholder_with_default(production_input, [50])

# Production environment call
result = session.run([dnn_1_input, dnn_2_input],
                     feed_dict={production_input: np.arange(50)})
```